# Como compartilhar um áudio do diretório interno raw?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Tenho vários áudios armazenados no diretório raw do app e gostaria de compartilhar com outros aplicativos, como o whatsapp por exemplo, porém achei muito confusa a documentação sobre como configurar o File provider

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="com.namepackage.fileprovider">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>

    </provider>
```

Ai vem a configuração do filepaths que tenho dúvida como resolver, está assim:
filepaths.xml

```
 <paths>
<files-path name="files" path="/" />
```

E o Intent em si:

```
  File imagePath = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "nomearquivo.mp3");
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"com.namepackege.fileprovider",
                imagePath);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        share.setType("audio/mp3");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(share);
```

Mas esse código não funciona, gostaria como preciso alterá-lo afim de que funcione

Comment: Me parece que não é possível apenas usando o FileProvider, segundo o CommonsWare nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742840/sharing-a-file-in-the-raw-folder-with-a-fileprovider), você tem duas alternativas: 1) Criar um FileProvider que faça acesso aos resources da pasta raw. 2) Usar o StreamProvider que implementa essa lógica: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma, [além de outras](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=share%20file%20raw%20android&oq=share%20file%20raw%20android&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.7471j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), de fazer isso, é salvar o arquivo primeiro no dispositivo antes de enviar. Veja um método simples:

```
public Uri shareItemRaw(int songInRawId, String songOutFile) {
    File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(songInRawId);

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, songOutFile));
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    return Uri.parse(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + songOutFile);
}
```

Sendo assim, você criar seu `intent` desta forma:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareItemRaw(R.raw.song, "song.mp3")); 
share.setType("audio/*");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(share);
```